# how to prevent invalid argument in foreach

Tags: php, curl, foreach

when I run this code it showing tow error first one is Undefined variable: item, second error is Invalid argument supplied for foreach() . I try to make an empty array as item. As a result, first notification removed but second one still appears. What's the problem with the invalid argument in foreach().

```
include_once('../../simple_html_dom.php');
    function scraping_digg() {
        // create HTML DOM
        $html = file_get_html('http://digg.com/');
        // get news block
        foreach($html->find('div.news-summary') as $article) {
            // get title
            $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
            // get details
            $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p', 0)->plaintext);
            // get intro
            $item['diggs'] = trim($article->find('li a strong', 0)->plaintext);
    $ret[] = $item;


        }
        // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);
            return $ret;
    }

    // "http://digg.com" will check user_agent header...
    ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');
    $ret = scraping_digg();
    foreach($ret as $v) {
        echo $v['title'].'<br>';
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>'.$v['details'].'</li>';
        echo '<li>Diggs: '.$v['diggs'].'</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: you could use a `try/catch` within the loop and use `continue` when an exception is raised

Comment: Try check if the array exists and it's not empty before looping over

Comment: the function `scraping_digg` returns a non-defined variable `$ret` on the first iteration of the loop. Also, looking at digg.com I cannot find any matching elements with class `news-summary`

Answer (score 0):

When building up items in an array, declare the array up front.  Secondly your function returns a value part way through, so the foreach after your function call has nothing to work with.

```
function scraping_digg() {
        // create HTML DOM
        $html = file_get_html('http://digg.com/');
        $ret = [];
        // get news block
        foreach($html->find('div.news-summary') as $article) {
            $item = [];
            // get title
            $item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);
            // get details
            $item['details'] = trim($article->find('p', 0)->plaintext);
            // get intro
            $item['diggs'] = trim($article->find('li a strong', 0)->plaintext);

            $ret[] = $item;
       }
        // clean up memory
        $html->clear();
        unset($html);

        return $ret;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs and need to debug this. I'll walk though my thought process in hopes you'll pick up better strategies for reasoning about your code.

You have two errors. Let's look at the first one that was raised because PHP encountered that problem first and that problem could have possible caused the second:

> Undefined variable: item

Where did you reference `$item`? You did things like `$item['title'] = trim($article->find('h3', 0)->plaintext);`, but logically - assigning it a new value wouldn't be a problem because PHP doesn't *need* the value of the variable. It must be something else.

You also did `$ret[] = $item;`. Okay great. If `$item` wasn't defined, PHP would freak out because it can't actually complete the operation with a reasonable result.

The question then is *why* would `$item` would be undefined during `$ret[] = $item;`? Clearly, you've done a `$item['title'] = 'whatever'`...? Well. What happens if that code never executed? If `$html->find('div.news-summary')` returns some 0 length array, the contents of the `foreach` loop never executes.

So there it is: **`$html->find('div.news-summary')` isn't doing what you think it's doing.** Maybe there isn't a div.new-summary element on the page? I don't know, but that something you should investigate.

Let's move on to the second error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This error showed up second, so we know it occured *after* `$ret[] = $item;`. The only `foreach` loop after that occured is

```
foreach($ret as $v) {
    echo $v['title'].'<br>';
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$v['details'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>Diggs: '.$v['diggs'].'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

It sounds like `$ret` isn't what you think it is. You've assigned `$ret` to the return value of `scrapping_digg()`, but what is *that* returning? It's clear that there is a problem between getting the return value of `scrapping_digg()` and the cause of the first error `$ret[]=$item`. The problem is that you never actually returned anything. PHP requires explictly calling `return` on functions. **You need to `return $ret`**.

```
function scraping_digg() {

    // ...

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);
    $ret[] = $item;\
    return $ret;
}
// ...
```

---

If you need to see what a variable is during execution (and you totally should do this) you can call `var_dump()` on it. This is a critical function when debugging.

```
$array = $html->find('div.news-summary')
var_dump($array)
```

> `array() (0); //Maybe. Or maybe something else.`

Once you get more comfortable with programming, you might look into using something like xDebug.